# HD44780 LCD Driver for STM32F3

Tags: stm32, hd44780

I am trying to interface an HD44780 LCD with an STM32F3 MCU. I'm using examples from the website http://controlsoft.mandela.ac.za/STM32F3-Discovery-Board/Example-programs/HD44780-LCD-(16x2-LCD) it seems it doesn't work. After the initialization I try to print "Hello World" and I get white upper line. Have you ever dealt with this driver or you got better ones? I would rather avoid usage an I2C adapter.

Comment: Double check your contrast. It sounds simple but I have had this before

Comment: The question is ill-posed. You start telling about your circuit and about an issue you had, but instead of asking for help on the issue you ask for a product recomendation? Bamboozled.

Comment: I think it's not because of contrast. When I make a debug, the program stops on the initialization function

Comment: Well, you know the reason. Try to analyze the initialization function. I'm using that library and everything had worked fine until my 16x2 LCD died for no good reason.